# Why do i get a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error with my custom RESTful actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a *RecordNotFound* error with my custom RESTful actions named *increase_order* and *decrease_order* in my *Admin::StylesController*, however the basic actions work well.

Ruby version :

```
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
```

Rails version :

```
Rails 4.1.4
```

Here is my error :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Style without an ID):
  app/controllers/admin/styles_controller.rb:50:in `set_style'
```

Here is my controller :

```
class Admin::StylesController < Admin::ApplicationController

  before_action :set_style, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :increase_order, :decrease_order]

  def index
    @styles = Style.all
  end

  def new
    @style = Style.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @style = Style.new(style_params)

    if @style.save
      redirect_to admin_styles_url, notice: 'Style was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @style.update(style_params)
      redirect_to admin_styles_url, notice: 'Style was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @style.destroy
    redirect_to admin_styles_url, notice: 'Style was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  def increase_order
    @style.update_attribute(:order, @style.order += 1)
    redirect_to admin_styles_url
  end

  def decrease_order
    @style.update_attribute(:order, @style.order -= 1)
    redirect_to admin_styles_url
  end

  private
    def set_style
      @style = Style.find(params[:id])
    end

    def style_params
      params.require(:style).permit(:name, :order, :cover)
    end
end
```

Here is my view :

```
%h3 Liste des Styles

%table.table.table-striped.table-condensed
  - @styles.each do |style|
    %tr
      %td= style.name

      %td= style.order

      %td.btn-group.btn-group-xs  # These two links work well.
        = link_to edit_admin_style_path(style), :class => 'btn btn-primary' do
          %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil
        = link_to [:admin, style], :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Voulez-vous supprimer ce style ?' }, :class => 'btn btn-primary' do
          %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove

      %td.btn-group.btn-group-xs  # These two links return a RecordNotFound error.
        = link_to admin_style_increase_order_path(style), :class => 'btn btn-primary' do
          %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-up
        = link_to admin_style_decrease_order_path(style), :class => 'btn btn-primary' do
          %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-down

= link_to new_admin_style_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' do
  %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
  Nouveau style
```

Here is my routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'welcome#index'

  namespace :admin do
    root 'dashboard#index'
    resources :styles do
      get 'increase_order'
      get 'decrease_order'
    end
  end

end
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `increase_order` and `decrease_order` actions should be defined as member action of your resource routes (so you get `id` param):

```
resources :styles do
  member do
    get :increase_order
    get :decrease_order
  end
end
```

and in view, to link to these actions:

```
link_to [:increase_order, :admin, style], :class => 'btn btn-primary' do
```

and

```
link_to [:decrease_order, :admin, style], :class => 'btn btn-primary' do
```

I also suggest that these actions should rather be accessible via `post` or `put` instead of `get` HTTP method.

Comment: @guduf Did you try my answer? Was it helpful?

Comment: Your answer works well with `get` actions, thank you very much. I tried to use `post` verb but i had this Routing Error `No route matches [GET] "/admin/styles/1/increase_order"`. Do you have a suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, you should add `method: :post` option to link, similarly to `method: :delete` in link to `destroy` action.